How does parquet read happens in the Modin distributed environment?
I am using Modin for reading the parquet file through panda. I have two clusters of 256 GB of RAM but even though duckdb on the single machine takes 50 seconds to go group by. Modin is going infinite and not giving the result. Here is my script:
import os
from dask.distributed import Client, SSHCluster
import logging
import psutil
import modin.config as modin_cfg
modin_cfg.Engine.put("dask")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import modin.pandas as pd
    client = Client("tcp://{ip}:8786")
    directory = '/root/parquet_files'
    df = pd.read_parquet(directory, columns=['L_SHIPINSTRUCT'])
    grouped_df = df.groupby('L_SHIPINSTRUCT').size().reset_index(name='count')
    print(grouped_df)

I want to understand how will the read of the parquet file will happen here? Will it read half file on one cluster and other half of another cluster or will do some kind of dividing and conquer technique to complete them parallel?
